# grep only subdirectories matching pattern

Tags: grep

I have a directory tree consisting of several thousand subdirectories, but I frequently need to grep only a small subset of those directories.  How can I `grep` only those subdirectories matching a pattern?

For example, suppose I have these subdirectories which I want to grep in:

```
...
...
...
/foo
/fooLib
/fooHandler
/fooGizmo
...
...
...
```

The `...` entries above represent the thousands of other directories I *don't* want to grep in.

Supposing I'm looking for all instances of `bar`, if I do this:

```
grep -n --recursive bar *
```

I would find what I'm looking for, but in all of the directories.  How can I search in only those subdirectories matching the pattern `foo*`?

Comment: Do you want to search only in `/foo` and friends? In `/foo` and `/foo/bar` and `/foo/bar/qux` and so on but not `/wibble/foo`? In `/foo` and `/wibble/foo` but not `/foo/bar`? In `/foo` and `/foo/bar` and `/wibble/foo` but not `/elsewhere`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use grep and find combination as below :

```
find /{foo,fooLib,fooHandler,fooGizmo} -type f -exec grep -l "test" {} \;
```

Or you can use

```
find /foo* -type f -exec grep -l "test" {} \;
```

Or using grep only

```
grep -R "test" /foo*
```

Comment: Can I do this without specifying the subdirectories explicityly? Rather, by using a wildcard such as `foo*`?

Comment: @JohnDibling yes i have updated exactly what you are saying :)

Comment: The latter suggestion (`grep -R "test" /foo*`) is exactly what I'm actually doing now, so I'll accept.

Comment: Thank you for this.  I'm using the first pattern, but would love to understand a few things about it - for example, what do the ending `{}` and backslash do?

Comment: This provides the lines matching the grep, but the location of the data (the file it's in) is lost. Is there any way to retain that?

Comment: I would love if answers like this actually explained what each part of the command-line means - to really learn, and extrapolate knowledge to other usage scenarios. I have absolutely no clue what the `\;` does.

Comment: Today, I read this elsewhere: "You can also use the `find` command to find a file and then carry out a command on that file. To do this use the command: `find pathname -name filename -print -exec command {}\;`. To be prompted for confirmation before the command is executed, use the command: `find pathname -name filename -print -ok command {}\;`. The command must be followed by a `\;`. The `{}` substitute the pathname of the file that is found as an argument to the command."

Comment: Isn't the last one supposed to be `grep -R "test" */foo*` ?

Answer (score 0):

try `grep foo* <other parts>` eg: `grep foo* -name "book*"`

Comment: If I'm looking for all instance of `bar` in all files in subdirectories named `foo*`, should this be like this: `grep --recursive bar ./foo*/*`?